# Fourier series specific value

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am learning Fourier series, and I must compute specific values for the Fourier series of the function $5x+7$ on the interval [-8,8].

The fourier series of a function on an interval [-L, L] is given by:
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n} \cos \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n} \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L}\right)
$$

- I find first $A_0$:
  $$
  A_{0}=\frac{1}{2 L} \int_{-L}^{L} 5x+7 d x
  $$
  The first term disappears (odd), and integrating 7 on the interval gives $A_0 = 7$
- Finding $A_m$
  $$
  A_{m}=\frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} (5x+7) \cos \left(\frac{m \pi x}{L}\right) d x \quad m=1,2,3, \ldots \\
  = \int_{-L}^{L} 5x \cos \left(\frac{m \pi x}{L}\right) d x + \int_{-L}^{L} 7 \cos \left(\frac{m \pi x}{L}\right) d x
  $$
  The first term is odd (odd * even = odd), the second is orthogonal, so $A_m=0$.
- Finding $B_m$ in the same manner:

$$
B_{m}=\frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} (5x+7) \sin \left(\frac{m \pi x}{L}\right) d x \quad m=1,2,3, \ldots \\
= \int_{-L}^{L} 5x \sin \left(\frac{m \pi x}{L}\right) d x + \int_{-L}^{L} 7 \sin \left(\frac{m \pi x}{L}\right) d x
$$
The second term is orthogonal, but the first is odd and can be integrated. By partial integration I find:
$$B_{m}=\frac{-1^{n+1}}{n \pi}$$

ie my Fourier series is:
$$7 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-1^{n+1} 80}{n \pi} \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x}{8}\right)$$

***EDIT: I asked about $f(0)$ and as @Ninad pointed in the comment, it was easy to calculate. I edited my question for clarity!***

**EDIT 2: added missing 80 in the fourier series.**

My issue is when calculating special values for this series. The site I am following is not covering this part and focusing in computing Fourier series (if I am not blind!: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/FourierSeries.aspx)
I cannot find a good example to follow (I don't understand how the person comes to their conclusion here: [Computing value of fourier series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129416/computing-value-of-fourier-series))

**So I would be grateful for an explanation on how one computes positive and negative values in the interval of a Fourier series, or some resources to read with exemplified process!**

**For example, how do I take f(2), and f(-2) and deal with the infinite sum?**

Comment: $f(0)$ looks like $7$ on that graph, I'm not sure what you're confused about.

Comment: Sorry, you are right! Looks like I cannot read the graph properly, I was reading the x-axis! But I am still confused about computing specific values. I edited my question, please have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of useful results about the pointwise convergence of Fourier series.

Take $f$ to be integrable on $[-L, L]$ and have a Fourier series $\sum a_n \cos (n\pi x/L) + b_n \sin (n\pi x /L)$.  Then two examples are

1. If $f$ has left and right derivative at $x\in [-L, L]$ then the Fourier series converges at $x$ to $\tfrac{1}{2}(f(x+)+f(x-))$ where $f(x\pm)$ indicate the limits of $f(x+t)$ as $t\to x$ from above and below.
2. If $f$ is continuous and the sum of the Fourier coefficients converges absolutely (i.e. $\sum |a_n| + |b_n|$ converges) then the  Fourier series converges to $f(x)$.

Use example 1 applied to your case, (assuming the coefficients are OK) we see that
$$
17 = f(2) = 7 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}80}{n\pi} \sin \left( \tfrac{1}{4}n\pi \right)
$$
where the infinite sum on the right will converge.  You can calculate values
$$
\sin \left( \tfrac{1}{4} n\pi \right)= \left\{ \begin{array}{2}
\sqrt{2}/2&n=1,3,9,11, \cdots\\
1&n=2,10, \cdots \\
-\sqrt{2}/2&n=5,7,13,15, \cdots \\
-1&n=6,14,\cdots \\
0&n=4,8,12,\cdots
\end{array}
\right. $$
and if you combine into groups of eight terms you have,
$$
\tfrac{1}{8}\pi = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left\{ -\frac{\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}}{8n+1} + \frac{1}{8n+2} - \frac{\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}}{8n+3} + \frac{0}{8n+4} + \frac{\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}/2}{8n+5} -\frac{1}{8n+6}+\frac{\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}/2}{8n+7}-\frac{0}{8n+8}
\right\}$$

Comment: Thank you very much @WA Don, that was very informative! So the important is to generate a series of terms that are repeating (cyclic?)

Comment: No - that won't always happen as it did in this case.  The important thing is that the Fourier series converges for the right type of $f$ so you can then say the $f(x)$ and the sum of the series are the same.  For example, to find $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} $$ you can develop a Fourier series for a simple function (Maybe $f(x) = |x|$ on $[-\pi,\pi]?)$ which gives the $1/n^2$ terms when $x=0$ and obtain the famous $$\sum \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: I will file this knowledge for later, we just started with Fourier and did not yet come ton convergence :)

Comment: Btw sorry there was a typo in my question, 80 is missing in B_m, let me fix that...

Comment: By the way I have a follow up question if you have time and energy :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4114511/fourier-serie-for-specific-value-follow-up-question