# Fourier serie for specific value (follow up question)

Tags: fourier-analysis

This is a follow-up question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4113304/fourier-series-specific-value).

I now understand that when calculating a specific value in a Fourier series, the goal is to identify a pattern and recognize a known infinite series or Taylor expansion.

I have the function $g(x) = 5x+7$, and its Fourier series: $\displaystyle7 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-1^{n+1} \cdot 80}{n \pi} \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x}{8}\right)$. I verified it was [correct](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/fourier-series-calculator/fourier%205x%2B7). **I now need to find f(5).**

As the teacher showed me, I took several values of $n$ for $\sin(\frac{5n\pi}{8})$ to try to identify my infinite sum.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\displaystyle
\begin{array}{lll}
\displaystyle
n=1 & \sin \left(\frac{5 \pi}{8}\right) & \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2} \\
n=2 & \sin \left(\frac{5 \pi}{4} \right) & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
n=3 & \sin \left(\frac{15 \pi}{8} \pi\right)=\sin \left(\frac{- \pi}{8}\right) & -\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2}\\
n=4 & \sin \left(\frac{5 \pi}{2} \pi\right)=\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) & 1\\
n=5 & \sin \left(\frac{25 \pi}{8} \pi\right)=\sin \left(\frac{ \pi}{8} \pi\right) &  \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2} \\
n=6 & \operatorname{an}\left(\frac{30 \pi}{8}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{-\pi}{4}\right) & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
n=7 & \sin\left(\frac{35 \pi}{8}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{3 \pi}{8}\right) & \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2}\\
n=8 & \sin\left(5 \pi\right) & 0\\
n=9 & \sin\left(\frac{45 \pi}{8}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{5 \pi}{8}\right) & \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2}\\
n=10 & \sin\left(\frac{50 \pi}{8}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
n=11 & \sin \left(\frac{55 \pi}{8} \pi\right)=\sin \left(\frac{- \pi}{8}\right) & -\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2}\\
\end{array}\\
...
\end{aligned}
$$

When I try to put it with coefficients I get:
$$
\begin{aligned}
7+\frac{80}{\pi} &\left(\frac{1}{1} \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{3} \frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2}-\frac{1}{4} \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2}+\frac{1}{5} \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2}\right.\\
&+\frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{7} \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2}-\frac{1}{8} \cdot 0+\frac{1}{9} \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2}-\frac{1}{10} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{11} \frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2} ...)
\end{aligned}
$$

*I am sorry in advance for typos, I have a tendency to miss them when typing latex!*

**Question: How do I see my series for f(5)?** I can't identify any Taylor series or familiar sum. Are there particular techniques to distinguish a series?

Comment: Hi.  I am not sure it is correct to say that the 'goal ' is to find a pattern.  Sometimes you might find the Fourier series generates an interesting pattern of terms, $e.g. \sum 1/n^2$, and equating series and function value allows you to obtain the sum;  but Fourier series have other uses.  In the case above, I cannot see any pattern and terms do not obviously cancel, so not sure what the question intended.    Moreover, I don't know of any guaranteed way to identify a pattern.

Comment: Alright. This might mean I have the wrong approach again! I had f(0), f(8), f(-8) which were equal to 7 because the sin terms cancels out, and f(-4) = -13 because of a pattern of -1, 0, 1, 0, which, together with the $\frac{-1^{n+1}}{n}$ term, that was corresponding to $tan^{-1}(1)$. So I assumed f(5) would also hide a pattern. What would your approach be to solve this question?

Comment: I am not sure what the objective of the question is.  Are you expected to find a pattern?  There might not be any other than the one you have derived.

Comment: No I am expected to solve the question. Solving for f(0), f(-8), f(8) was fast, solving for f(-4) requested to find a pattern in four steps. But I don't know how I should think for solving for f(5).

Comment: OK.  I am not sure what you can do if no pattern is apparent.  Maybe stop at the sum of $\sin$ terms.  Note that the cycle must be $n=1,2,\cdots,16$ in this case to get a full period of $\sin (5n\pi/8)$.

Comment: Ok, I will develop a bit later, thank you for the tips!

Comment: Ok now I understand better your reply to my previous question!! "If  is continuous and the sum of the Fourier coefficients converges absolutely (i.e. ∑||+|| converges) then the Fourier series converges to ()." 
I did not understood the part "the sum of the Fourier coefficients converge absolutely", because I don't know how I was supposed to know that... But the point is that this series converges so the reply is f(5) = g(5) = 32, because convergence! If you copy paste your reply I will choose it as answer :)

Comment: Thanks - as long as your happy.  I won't cut and past because I'd like to answer more thoroughly to make it a good answer but not inclined to put extra work in!

Comment: Of course! I just did not want to take credit from you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was clearly stated by [@WA Don](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4113304/fourier-series-specific-value/4113427?noredirect=1#comment8507576_4113427) in my previous question and I wish I can select it as a solution for this question as well.

I did not understood the condition (2.) at he time, because I simply did not understood how one could take all Fourier coefficients (I still don't actually!).

From WA Don answer:

***2.  If $f$ is continuous and the sum of the Fourier coefficients converges absolutely (i.e. $\sum |a_n| + |b_n|$ converges) then the  Fourier series converges to $f(x)$.***

The same theorem was available in my book, Differential Equations with Boundary-Value Problems:

[image]

In conclusion, since the function $g(x) = 5(x) + 7$ on the interval $[-8,8]$ is continuous, its Fourier series $ 7 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}80}{n\pi} \sin \left( \tfrac{1}{4}n\pi \right)$ converges to $5(x) + 7$, that is f(5) = 32.

Comment: Hi.  The second condition (see [wikipedia[(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence) entry) means that the sum of the positive values $|a_n|, |b_n|$ of the coefficients - $80/(n\pi)$ - converges to a finite number.  This is not the case because (ignoring $80/\pi$) you would sum terms of $1/n$ and this sum gows without limit (diverges to $\infty$).  Thus you cannot use condition 2 but condition 1 works fine because $f$ has left and right derivatives and a discontinuity at the ends of the interval where $f(8)\neq f(-8)$.

Comment: So you mean that I can use *either* of conditions, and both do not need to be true?

Comment: Yes - see the page reference